# Remove slider from html

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, frontend, web-frontend

I have this landing page template and I wanted to remove slider from it. The slider is rendered by `camera.js` file. Every time I try to remove the js file or disable the slider the full container gets disappear.

I have uploaded the code on git. I tried to remove the slider/banner initialization function itself from the js file but it also resulted in disappearing if the banner. I cannot see any errors on the console.

```
// DOM ready function
jQuery(document).on('ready', function() {
    (function ($) {
       removePlaceholder ();
     BannerSlider ();   //tried to remove this
     wowAnimation ();
     mixitupGallery ();
     testimonialSlider ();
     portfolioSlider ();
     partnersLogo ();
     CounterNumberChanger ();
     scrollToTop ();
     contactFormValidation ();
     closeSuccessAlert ();
     themeAccrodion ();
     priceRanger ();
     productValue ();
     productSlider ();
  })(jQuery);
});
```

I can understand this might be the most basic thing but any help regarding this would do the work.

git link : [Landing Page](https://github.com/raghavpatnecha/landingpage)

Comment: I tried, and had no issue after deleting the `BannerSlider ();` line, maybe if you remove (or comment) the lines linked to the camera slider in `index.html` lines 704 to 706

Comment: @BSO by removing the slider I mean keeping the image as static which is not happening